# I just want to permanently add some html tags to existing HTML using JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have to add some tag value to existing HTML file through jsoup.

The below is the sample html file

**Sample HTML**

```html
<html>
    <h1>header</h1>
</html>
```

The below is the code that I tried to append value after h1 tag in existing html file.

```
File f=new File(".//output//Test.html");
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(f, "UTF-8");
Element element=doc.select("h1").first();
System.out.println(element.text());
element.after("<h2>TEST</h2>");
element.append("<h2>TEST</h2>");
```

But the html file is not updated It still looks like the original one.

**Expected output:**

```html
<html>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
</html>
```

I just want to permanently append some run time values right after h1 tag with existing file.

Any leads....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write your java code like:

```
File f=new File(".//output//Test.html");
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(f, "UTF-8");
Element element=doc.select("h1").first();
System.out.println(element.text());
element.after("<h2>TEST</h2>");
element.append("<h2>TEST</h2>");
try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("your-target-path")) {
    printWriter.write(doc.html());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```